# Squarespace to WordPress

Tags: xml, wordpress, migration, squarespace

I was wondering if anyone can share some ideas on how to successfully migrate a large website from Squarespace to WordPress?

Steps I've already taken.

- I've downloaded the XML file from Squarespace
- I've installed the WordPress Importer Plugin
- I've imported the XML file into my local dev WordPress install
- I've installed the Import External Images Plugin

The issue I'm having is that the WordPress Importer Plugin fails to download some images from the XML file.

Also the Import External Images Plugin is not able to recognize some of the images from the Squarespace XML file.

The pictures show but are hotlinked to Squarespace which means once I upload to production environment and cancel the squarespace account, the images will be broken.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get all the images properly uploaded to my local dev site and then migrate to production site.

I've Googled this question with no good solution so far. 
Any Ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Post the XML file, might yield some insights.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download your wordpress exported xml file and follow following steps:

**Step 1 — Download Your Media Files**
FTP to your site and download the folder /wp-content/uploads/

**Step 2 — Create Amazon S3 Folder**
Setup an account with Amazon S3. This is a affordable way to store files for VERY cheap.

**Step 3 — Upload**
Create new Bucket (Not so fancy name for folder) in S3 where we are going to upload our files, preserving the same file structure.
The url path for my new images will be:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/usoidudiod/uploads/
We now have our images stored and backed up on Amazon S3.

**Step 4 — Edit The XML File**
Open your WordPress XML file in your favourite text edited. I use Sublime on the Mac.
Now replace all instances of:
/wp-content/uploads/
with you new Amazon S3 folder url.

Mine looked like this:
http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/
replaced with
https://s3.amazonaws.com/usoidudiod/uploads/

**Step 5 — Import**
Now go back to 
Squarespace > Settings > Advanced > Import/Export > Click Import > Chose WordPress > Select Advanced.
Click the **‘Add a file’** and upload your newly edited XML file.

**Fingers crossed that should all work for you now.** :)

Answer (score 0):

Squarespace detects that user agent in HTTP header is `WordPress` and rejects requests, they don't want to lose clients, very nice undocumented obstacle from Squearespace!

**Solution**

In core file `wp-includes/class-http.php`, replace line

```
'user-agent' => apply_filters( 'http_headers_useragent', 'WordPress/' . get_bloginfo( 'version' ) . '; ' . get_bloginfo( 'url' ) ),
```

with

```
'user-agent' => "Mozilla/5.0",
```

Both WP importer and 'Import External Images' plugin will start working properly

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to parse the XML and download the images and and any uploaded files from there. We had the same problem where we thought we'd got all the downloadable from a Squarespace site but hadn't.

We ended writing a script in `R` which we posted to GitHub as a package.

https://github.com/Deducive/sqspR

There are separate functions to get the download links for images and for any uploaded files such as PDFs.